# Qt QPushButton style sheet properties not applied

Tags: c++, css, qt

I have a Qt application that styles a QPushButton. Basically in normal state, the push button background colour is red and the text blue and when pressed, the button background colour is blue and the text is red.

This works great for mouse events/presses but for a touch event the pressed properties are not applied. The button functions correctly, i.e. the button does what it should when it is pressed but the appearance is not applied as per the style sheet. My style sheet is:

```
QPushButton#myPushButtonName { 
background-color:#ff0000; color:#0000ff; 
}

QPushButton#myPushButtonName:pressed { 
background-color:#0000ff; color:#ff0000; 
}
```

Its like it is ignoring the touch event in the style sheet.

Any ideas??

Comment: What is your QStyleSheet?

Comment: my stylesheet is: 
QPushButton#myPushButtonName { 
background-color:#ff0000;
color:#0000ff;
}
QPushButton#myPushButtonName:pressed {
background-color:#0000ff;
color:#ff0000;
}

Comment: Write it in your question.

Comment: hmm, looks like according to this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html that the :pressed pseudo-state indicates a press of the mouse.

Comment: It is and I don't know any other state for touch event.

Comment: Use QML. It is designed much better to work with touch input.